# gnu manpage, two versions of documentation on "env" command

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, gnu

I'm new to shell programming and I'm currently studying the `env` command on ubuntu.

I was checking the `env` command on [GNU manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=env&op=&cx=003883529982892832976%3A5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%2F&ref=&ss=115j13225j2) and there seem to be two versions of documentation on `env`

[image]

So I was just wondering, why is there two version of the same command? What is the difference between the two of them?

I just started learning shell and this is causing me a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual for different versions of the same command to exist, for instance on different operating systems. In this case, you've found man pages for POSIX env as well as coreutils env.

POSIX is a joint specification for how a Unix-style operating system should behave. It contains many interfaces, such as real-time libraries with threads and clocks, C programming language with standard library, and so on. In this case, it specifies a baseline of how the env command should behave.

coreutils is a GNU package contains a set of programs considered "core" to an operating system. On GNU systems such as GNU/Linux, this is likely to be what implements the env command. It has its own documentation both so it doesn't rely on separate documentation like the POSIX one, and to document any extensions and differences from standard.

In this case, GNU coreutils env has a couple of switches not present in POSIX coreutils, such as unsetting specific variables and outputting NUL-delimited lists.

Comment: hi Yann, thank you very much for the answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what you said, my understanding is that the POSIX `env` is like a baseline, containing the basic command `env` should perform. The GNU `env` is like a extension with additional functions, based on top of the POSIX `env`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Basically yes. Note in particular that POSIX env is a specification, not an implementation; a particular env may be POSIX compliant, but there's no single env that is *the* POSIX env. Also, frequently the tools predate POSIX, so it may be the spec that is written to match reality.

Comment: yeah, that makes perfect sense now. Thanks again for helping out! really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

One manual page is related to the env shell command you're working with and another is related to programming libraries for env such as env.h.

Comment: Here's a learning moment: a man page named `env(1)` is in man section 1, which is user commands. System calls are in section 2 and library functions in section 3. Some header files are documented in section 7. These man pages are both for the env command.

Comment: There are also three distinct section 3 man pages, that describe env calls in a variety of languages, but OP's image did clarify he means the two env(1) pages.

Comment: Right I didn't pay attention to the question in this case I was referring to env(1) and env(3). The difference between the 2 env(1) pages would be one is for the POSIX command and one for the GNU command. GNU programs are the ones you'd likely have on Linux and they usually add extensions to the POSIX version.  If you wanted to make a cross platform script it's important to use the POSIX command format as other Unix OSes may not have the GNU command installed.